# Javascript not working in iOS WebView

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile

I've been racking my brains thinking that my javascript wasn't working. However, it's working on my iPhone browsers (chrome & safari). I think the webview is causing the issue.

It's using jquerymobile and all other functions are working correctly. However, javascript alert function isn't and also a XMLHttpRequest).

I'm calling the jquery /mobile from within the web pages like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         function loadXMLDoc()
         {
         var xmlhttp;
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
           {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
           }
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
           {
           if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
             {
             document.getElementById("gen").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
             }
         }
         xmlhttp.open("GET","randomNumbers.php?min=1&max=49&count=6",true);
         xmlhttp.send();
         }
      </script>
      <script>
    $(document).on('click','#gen-button',function() {
    loadXMLDoc();

});
      </script>
```

My xcode is just simply:

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.domain.co.uk/lotto/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Is there something I need to add to my webview control to allow certain javascript to work?

Comment: U r calling a URL right . Then where did u calling this javaScript file

Comment: I'm calling the javascript file from within the page